# WHILE and DO-WHILE loop not executing and gets stuck at the output

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

**FOR** loop is executing but this code is not executing for **while** and **do-while** and it gets stuck after I enter the input, please help me, I am using VS Code as my IDE, compiler -- GNU GCC.

P.S :- I am executing this code on arch linux.

P.S.S :- This code is executing effectively on Windows 10 though.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
    int i,f = 1,n;
    printf("Enter a number :: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    i = 1;
    do
    {
        f *= i;
    }while (i <= n);
     printf("The Factorial of %d is  %d\n\n",n,f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does the loop get exited?  How does `i` ever reach `n`?

Comment: neither `i` nor `n` change in loop body, so condition is always true

Comment: inside `Do-While` loop neither `i` not `n` is altered.

Comment: The loop doesn't get exited as I said it gets stuck after I enter any numeral input for ex:- 5

Comment: oh right I forget to add ```i++``` . Thanks for helping me

Comment: Yep right now its working Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    do
    {
        f *= i;
    }while (i <= n);
```

nothing is changing `n` or `i`. So if `i <= n` it will be infinitive loop , otherwise it will exit in first comparison.